# statistical inference - what about population size?

Tags: inference, central-limit-theorem, finite-population

I'll try to explain my question since it's very theoretical.
In general, using statistical inference we try to estimate parameters of the population based on a sample.
Several theorems show that as our sample size is larger, our predictions are more accurate. However, from what I've seen, the weak/ strong law of large numbers and the central limit theorem discuss the limit when N goes to infinity.
Why is the ratio of the sample to the population size not used instead?

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Loosely speaking: in most cases it makes things easier to assume *infinite* population size, so we do so; there are cases where we assume finite population (see questions tagged [tag:finite-population]) and then we take into consideration the population size s well.

Comment: In many practical situations there isn't any finite "population," nor would it even make sense to pretend there is one.  How many samples of seawater are there, or possible observations of a star, or adult human beings (who ever will live)?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. As per @whuber 's answer, I understand your answer, yet not sure I agree with your statement. I think that many of the questions people are dealing with do have finite population (current clients, people's height/weight, elections, accidents, etc.)
It's true that in science, if you look at statistics used in thermodynamics or quantum theory, such finite population has no meaning. Again, thank you both for your answers.

Comment: If one is analyzing data about "current clients," that's usually to make inferences about future clients; there is no finite population of heights and weights; nor is there any conceivable "population" of accidents.  You seem to be using the word "population" in the same sense everyone else would use "sample."